# Selecting multiple fabric objects using the [Ctrl] key

Tags: jquery, fabricjs

**Use Case**:
I select a fabric object primarily. Next, I press and hold the [Ctrl] and select another fabric object. At this point, both the objects must be highlighted (similar to shapes drawn in Microsoft Word).

Is there any way to accomplish this?

P.S: I wish to accomplish this **without** using the mouse-drag selection.

Comment: This already happens when you hold shift

Comment: In which version of fabric JS is this present? I am using 1.0.0 which I got from the Customisation demo. This sure isn't happening in this version. Also, is there any link where I may find a demo for the same? Thank You.

Comment: P.S: The objects that I am creating using fabric are the ones that I have created by subclassing the ones already present (ex: iLine, iText).

Comment: In both MacOS and Windows, you can achieve this with shift. You can try to bind/unbind keys to copy the effect for ctrl

Answer (score 3):

After debugging through the fabric-1.0.0.js file, I found out that my **canvas.selection** was set to false.
This was an error on my part as it was I who had set this value earlier in order to avoid mouse-drag group selection.

Thanks @kangax for letting me know about the use of shiftKey in fabric nevertheless!
Although I am unable to select your comment as the right answer, I am stating this right here.

Comment: Glad you found the problem

Comment: By the way, thank you @kangax for bringing about Fabric JS. Just wanted to say that.. :)

Comment: we can change default multiple selection (shift Key) using property selectionKey.
`fabric.Canvas("myCanvas", { selection: true, selectionKey: "ctrlKey" });`